# Spatial Create View table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm using `Qgis 2.18.17` with `Postgres 9.6`.

I have a feature line (below) and I want to create a feature AREA table VIEW with the following SQL using DB manager of Qgis.

[image]

```
select   distinct  row_number()  OVER () as id2 , (st_dump(st_polygonize(a.shape))).geom as shape
FROM   aaa_teste_qgis a.
```

The result table is:

[image]

When I try to create the VIEW and put on screen I receive the following msg.

> "Camada não é válida: A camada dbname='bdd' host=xx.xx.x.x port=5432
>   user='TEST' password='xxxxxxxx' sslmode=allow key='id2' srid=4674
>   type=Polygon table="TEST"."aaaaaaa" (shape) sql= não é uma camada
>   válida e não pode ser adicionada ao mapa"

Then a note that ID2 column has the same number one.

Could you give a help?

Comment: the distinct there isn't doing anything, you need to paste output  of `\d aaa_teste_qgis` in psql

Comment: "distinct " is wrong, I don´t undertand where use "\d"

Comment: select     row_number()  OVER () as id2 , (st_dump(st_polygonize(a.shape))).geom as shape
FROM   aaa_teste_qgis a